# Saving timestamp and tcp window size as CSV file or txt file

Tags: wireshark

[image: PCAP file]

Hello

Is that possible to save only timestamp and TCP window size from a capture file (PCAP file)?

How can I do it?

How can I plot a graphic of timestamp X TCP window size? Wireshark can do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
tshark -r "1.pcap" -Tfields -e frame.time_epoch -e tcp.window_size_value >> arquivo.txt
```

Comment: @EricLeschinski: This "code" solve the problem:I did not understand why people vote to delete the answer!